# A First Order Definition of the Mod Function

Tags: modular-arithmetic, first-order-logic, peano-axioms

Is there a good FOL definition of a $\bmod$ predicate in the language of Peano arithmetic? I tried $M(x,n,r) \equiv Ey(x=ny+r)$ but I don't like it very much.

Comment: If it is predicate which says $x$ and $r$ are congruent modulo $n$, then it is wrong. If it is the predicate which says $r$ is the remainder when $x$ is divided by $n$, it is also wrong. What predicate are you trying to define?

Comment: A predicate which says r is the remainder when x is divided by n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to say that $r$ is the remainder when $x$ is divided by $n$. I will assume that variables range over the non-negative integers.

So we want to say that there exists a $q$ such that $x=nq+r$ and $r\lt n$. To say $r\lt n$, we need to say that $\lnot (r=n)$ and there is a $t$ such that $t+r=n$. Putting things together, we get
$$\exists q\exists t((x=nq+r)\land \lnot(r=n)\land (t+r=n)).$$

Note that if we use this definition then we have decided that the predicate $M(x,n,r)$ will not hold if $n=0$. If we want to make another choice in the case $n=0$, suitable modification can be made.

Comment: Thanks. I also need a definition for finite rings. Would you also have one that says x and r are congruent modulo n?

Comment: I am not sure even of the definition of congruence. If $x,r,n$ are ring elements, maybe what is meant is that the difference $x-y$ is an integer multiple of $n$. If this is the intended informal definition of congruence, then I very much doubt there is a definition in the usual first-order language of rings. Have not written out a proof, but it will be the usual Compactness argument, or alternately we can use an ultraproduct.

Comment: $x-y$ can be written as $x+(-1)y$. Maybe $z+1=0 and x+zy$ divisible by $n$?

Comment: There is no trouble dealing with subtraction. The question is what one means by congruence in the ring. If we mean that there is a **ring element** $q$ such that $x=qn+r$, then the sentence of your post does it. But if we mean that $x-r$ is the ring element $n$ times an **integer**, that's entirely different. (The subtraction is no trouble, easily dealt with in ring language.)

Comment: Great! I am actually interested in the case where ring element satisfies.